# Сбрасывается переменна в onLocationChanged

Tags: java, android

При запуске Service  я получаю id(к примеру равный 3), но когда вызывается onLocationChanged id становится равным 0, как его сохранить, чтоб постоянно пользоваться им?

````
public class GPSTrackerService extends Service implements LocationListener {

   private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
   private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

   protected LocationManager locationManager;
   private SendData sendData = new SendData();
   private SharedPreferences sPref;
   private int id;

   @Nullable
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       startLoc();
       return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
   }

   private void startLoc() {
       locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
       if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           return;
       }
       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
               LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
               MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
               MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
               new GPSTrackerService()
       );
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       id = getUserId();
       super.onCreate();
   }

  
   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
       try {
           sendLocation(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   public void sendLocation(double longitude, double latitude) throws JSONException {
       System.out.println(id);
   }

   private int getUserId() {
       return sPref.getInt("id", -1);
   }
} ```
````

Comment: `new GPSTrackerService()` - вы передаёте в `LocationManager` новый экземпляр класса, не имеющий никакого отношения к текущему сервису. Передайте вместо этого `this` - это ссылка на текущий экземпляр.

Comment: Попробуй сделать id как public